# Install OpenSSH using cmd/terminal only?

Tags: windows, ssh, installation, remote-access

Is it possible to [install OpenSSH](https://winaero.com/blog/enable-openssh-server-windows-10/) entirely using the cmd/terminal? All of the solutions I'm finding on Google require navigating to the Settings app:

https://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Windows-10-install-SSH-server.png

Answer (score 4):

On a sufficiently recent Windows 10 system this works

```
PS > Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name 'OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0'

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False
```

To check the status use this

```
PS > Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? {$_.Name  -like '*ssh*' }

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

You could also install via chocolatey

```
# https://chocolatey.org/packages/openssh

PS > choco install openssh
```

If you really want lots of control you can also download the release [directly from github](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/) and manually install things.  There is an [ansible role](https://github.com/jborean93/ansible-role-win_openssh/) that installs using the manual method that you could probably reverse engineer if you wanted to figure it out for some other system.

Comment: Here's the official Microsoft documentation on these commands: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse